# Insert score in a button game function

Tags: python, function, insert, pygame

I have this code for a button that is pressable:

```
def button(msg,xloc,yloc,xlong,ylong,b1,b2,action=None):

    hover = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if xloc < hover [0] < xloc+xlong and yloc< hover [1] < yloc+ylong:
        pygame.draw.rect(display, b1, (xloc ,yloc ,xlong,ylong))
        if click [0]==1 and action != None:
            action()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactiveButton, (xloc ,yloc ,xlong,ylong))
    label = pygame.font.SysFont("arial",16)
    textSurf, textBox = textMsg(msg, label)
    textBox.center = ((xloc +(300)),((yloc +(150))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textBox)
```

and the code for the scoring is:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:   
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        score+=1
        print (score)
```

I would like have a score that – upon pressing the correct button in the choices in order to answer in a quiz game –  will be displayed and incremented by 1. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is missing something... A question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way to implement a button that I know. Create a rect for the button and draw it with `pygame.draw.rect` (or blit an image). For the collision detection, check if the `event.pos` of a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event collides with the rect and then just increment the `score` variable.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

GRAY = pg.Color('gray15')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 30)
    button_rect = pg.Rect(200, 200, 50, 30)

    score = 0
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print('Button pressed.')
                        score += 1

        screen.fill(GRAY)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, button_rect)
        txt = font.render(str(score), True, BLUE)
        screen.blit(txt, (260, 206))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

Addendum: Actually, I would implement a button with the help of classes, sprites and sprite groups. If you don't know how classes and sprites work, I'd recommend to check out [Program Arcade Games (chapter 12 and 13)](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=en#section_12).

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
GRAY= pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 30)


# The Button is a pygame sprite, that means we can add the
# instances to a sprite group and then update and render them
# by calling `sprite_group.update()` and `sprite_group.draw(screen)`.
class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, callback):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((50, 30))
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.callback = callback

    def handle_event(self, event):
        """Handle events that get passed from the event loop."""
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print('Button pressed.')
                # Call the function that we passed during the
                # instantiation. (In this case just `increase_x`.)
                self.callback()


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

        self.x = 0
        self.button = Button((200, 200), callback=self.increase_x)
        self.buttons = pg.sprite.Group(self.button)
        self.done = False

    # A callback function that we pass to the button instance.
    # It gets called if a collision in the handle_event method
    # is detected.
    def increase_x(self):
        """Increase self.x if button is pressed."""
        self.x += 1

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()
            self.clock.tick(30)

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True

            for button in self.buttons:
                button.handle_event(event)

    def run_logic(self):
        self.buttons.update()

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(GRAY)
        self.buttons.draw(self.screen)
        txt = FONT.render(str(self.x), True, BLUE)
        self.screen.blit(txt, (260, 206))

        pg.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().run()
    pg.quit()
```